# By removing scientific notation the data does not display correctly

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I have the following data:

```
 dput(mydata)
c(5.19897453503481e+28, 3.33164060868048e+28, 4.28127522948889e+28, 
5.64348827422289e+28, 5.72642655371425e+28)
```

Whenever I remove the scientific notation of data in R using this:

```
 output <- format(mydata, scientific=FALSE);
```

The data appears like that:

```
[1] "51989745350348091512680664620" "33316406086804775072084246080" "42812752294888867976688624200" "56434882742228873664844820404"
[5] "57264265537142484298068002406"
```

Which is abit different from my original data in bigquery? Does anyone know why?

Comment: What do you mean with "a bit different"?  I suspect you stumble upon the finite precision of R double (about 15 digits) but please be more specific if this is not the case.

Comment: The lats two digits are different, it seems somehow R round the data, I did not find a pattern in these differences to explain here.

Comment: The _last_ two digits?  You mean like '20' in the case of the first number (with ```scientific = FALSE```)?  How do you even know how is it supposed to look like?  Only about 15 digits are reliable if using the standard R ```numeric```.  Use multiprecision numbers (Rmpfr as suggested) if you need more digits.

Comment: I can see the real number in Bigquery. Unfortunately Rmpfr did not work too

Comment: OK, in that case I suspect R imports the numbers as ```numeric``` from bigquery and looses precision in the process.  You may try to import those as character strings and convert to Rmpfr-s thereafter.  Sorry, I don't know bigquery but it is a solution for SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `Rmpfr` package

```
library(Rmpfr)
mpfr(mydata, precBits = 1024)
```

Comment: thanks four your solution, it doesn't work for me. The data originally have string format

Comment: @MFR the `mpfr` is supposed to provide the precision you expect for a big number.  In the `dput` you provided, I find `e+28` as the suffix, so I am not sure by what criteria you are using to suggest `it doesn't work`